# when to use List<T>.BinarySearch?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, search, binary-search

The generic `List<T>` in .NET has a [`BinarySearch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. `BinarySearch()` is an efficient algorithm for searching large datasets.  I think I read that if everyone in the world was listed in a phone book then binary search could find any person within 35 steps.  At what point should a `BinarySearch()` be used on a `List` as opposed to using the standard `.Where` clause with a lambda? How big should the data set be before switching from `Where` to `BinarySearch`?  Or does `Where` already use a binary search behind the scenes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When to use `List<T>.BinarySearch`?

As you can read in the [documentation manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Searches the **entire sorted `List<T>`** for an element using the default comparer and returns the zero-based index of the element.

Furthermore it can only be used to match a given **element**, not a predicate since a generic predicate would defeat the order constraint.

So the list has to be sorted, either by the default comparator, or by a given comparator:

```
public int BinarySearch(T item)                        //default comparator
public int BinarySearch(T item, IComparer<T> comparer) //given comparator
```

The algorithm runs in *O(log n)* time whereas the `where` clause runs in *O(n)* time, which means in practice it will nearly always outperform the second (unless it is very likely the element will be found in the front of the list).

> Or does `.Where` already use a binary search behind the scenes?

No, it can't since. A `List<T>` is not always sorted. First checking whether the list is sorted, or sorting the the list would require a computational effort of *O(n)* or *O(n log n)* respectively which would be the same or even more expensive than linear search. In other words, first checking whether the list is sorted and then - if that's the case - perform binary search would be more expensive than performing a linear search. A linear search can handle both unordered lists and predicates but at a much larger cost.

Answer (score 3):

> At what point should a `BinarySearch()` be used on a List as opposed to using the standard `Where` clause with a lambda?

Any time the list is sorted relative to the value you're searching for, `BinarySearch` will (on average) give you better performance than `Where` regardless of size.

If the list is unordered, or in an order that does not correspond to the value you're looking for (you can't use a binary search to find a person in the phone book by *first* name) then `BinarySearch` will not give you the right results.

Note that it only returns *one index*, while `Where` will give you *all items* that match the criteria, but you can search on either side of the found element if there are duplicates (`BinarySearch` gives you *one* index that matches, not necessarily the *first* index).

Obviously the bigger the list, the more improvement `BinarySearch` is going to give you.

> does `Where` already use a binary search behind the scenes?

No - it iterates through the list in physical order.